# access int variable from Java and use it in Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I am using chart.js to create a metrics dashboard. To get the values that I will use for the chart I am using Java to access a MS SQL server.

I was able to grab the values (int x=rs.getInt("example"))  from the server but now I need to use those variables in my JavaScript code as the different values of the chart.

I read up on .jsp and wasn't sure if this is what I was looking for. I had questions like: do I need a .java/.js file if I have a .jsp file? Do I put my java code straight into the .jsp file like so, <% 'code' %>? Do I link the .jsp file to my HTML?

Very sorry if this is a duplicate but I wasn't able to find a very concrete answer.

Comment: You're asking for a tutorial, it seems

Comment: Do you want the values to be available when the page loads, or to be retrieve from the server at some point after loading?

Comment: It sounds like you may want to use something like AJAX to send data from your Java server to your JavaScript client.  I'm not 100% sure on the details, but you would basically set up your Java server to expose a path in your domain that sends the data read from SQL Server as a JSON string.  Your JavaScript code would then ask for this from the server (using jQuery or whatever JavaScript library you're using), and display the data when it's loaded by getting it from the JSON.  Again, I'm not really a web dev person, but check out AJAX tutorials and see if it's what you need.

Comment: @DBS I would like the values to be available when the page loads

Comment: Alternatively, if you're planning on running this all on one local computer, you may just want your java code to serve the SQL Server data on a socket, and have your javascript code connect to this using websockets and render your dashboard using that.  That way, you wouldn't have to deal with the details of JSP or setting up a web server.

Comment: `available when the page loads` - so they are fixed on load time, and never change? Then include them as plain integer constants in the script. (no need for another round trip to the server)

Comment: @mjn my project would run the java code everytime the page is reloaded so that it can use the most recent values for the variables

Comment: @Blue_vision If i were to have this all run on a local computer then I would be the only one that can see the chart. I am writing this app for a company and would like the app to be accessible by a link.

Comment: @TrevorScottCohen then you are probably looking for AJAX or a similar solution.  A quick google search should give you guides and tutorials galore on using AJAX with a Java/JSP backend, and whatever JavaScript library you are using.  If you run into a specific problem with your implementation, you can ask it on StackOverflow as another question :)

Answer (score 0):

supposing your data is an integer, get your data from database somehow and save in a `int` variable

```
int jspData = 6;   // contains your jsp data

// In JSP(HTML)
<input id="jsp-data" type="hidden" value="<%=jspData%>" />

// In JavaScript
var data = document.getElementById('jsp-data').value;
```

now, you can use that `data` in JavaScript.

*Note: This works is the integer is predefined. For dynamic values, you must put `<input>` inside the loop you use to get data from database. Also, you will need to generate unique `id` for each `<input>` the loop creates. This can be done by mixing an `ID_STRING` with `loop-counter` variable. For e.g. `input_1`, `input_2`, `input_3`, so on*